# Origin of values in a steam table

Tags: thermodynamics

Are values in steam tables within the liquid-vapor coexistence region obtained using the Maxwell lever rule (which motivates the definition of quality), or by using a specific equation of state ?

Comment: They are based on low pressure heat capacities of liquid water and water vapor (as a function of temperature), and empirical equations of state for liquid water and water vapor. The only values in the saturated steam tables are for the saturated liquid and saturated vapor, not for combinations of the the two.

Comment: The expression for quality $x=(v_O-v_L)/(v_G-v_L)$ (here $v_G$ is volume for saturated vapor, $v_L$ is for saturated liquid, $v_O$ for the point of interest within the coexistence region) is identical to what one would get from the Maxwell lever rule, hence the query.

Comment: I didn't realize that is what you were asking.  Yes, of course the lever rule is applicable.

Comment: @Frost I didn't know what you meant by the lever rule either. Its the sane equation as mine, rearranged. See update.

Comment: Do you see that your equation is no different than mine? In your equation you determine  the quality $x$ given the property of the mixture $v$ (or your $v_o$). In my equation you determine the property of the mixture (in my case $h$) given the quality $x$ of the mixture. The two are equivalent.

Comment: @Frost OK, then I will update my answer based on your rephrase.

Comment: @Frost I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chet Miller has already explained the origin of the values in the saturated steam tables.

In order to determine the values of the specific properties for the liquid vapor mixture, you need to be given the quality $x$ of the steam, which is the fraction of the mixture that is saturated vapor. Then, for example, the specific enthalpy of the steam mixture is

$$h=xh_{g}+(1-x)h_{f}$$

Where $h_{g}$ and $h_{f}$ are the specific enthalpies of the saturated vapor and saturated liquid respectively, from the steam tables. The same equation applies to $s$, $u$, and $v$.

Note that this is the same equation that you call the "lever rule" if you rearrange it and put $x$ on the left side of the equation.

> To rephrase my query: Whether the Maxwell lever rule (which motivates
> the definition of quality), is actually used in obtaining values for
> the coexistence region in the steam table.

The term "lever rule" had a familiar ring to it, but I didn't remember any reference to in connection with the steam tables. Then I remembered the term lever rule being used in material science in analyzing binary phase diagrams of alloys.

FIG 1 shows the use of the rule in connection with the liquid and solid phases of an allow.

FIG 2 shows the equation for determining any given property of the liquid/vapor mixture ($v$, $u$, $h$, ore $s$)

Iv'e highlighted (boxed) the analogous equations.

So in answer to your question, the term "lever rule" is not actually used in connection with determining a property of the steam liquid/vapor mixture, given the quality, or determining the quality given the value of a steam liquid/vapor mixture. However, the approach actually used is definitely analogous to the lever rule.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The Maxwell lever rule was originally motivated by the mechanically unstable isotherms of non-ideal gas models (such as van der Waals gas) in the liquid-vapor coexistence region. Hence, I was curious to know whether the method has been used to actually compute values from the steam table in that region. The identical definition of quality was a red herring.

Comment: @Frost Got it. Gut did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you.